# App crashing because lateinit App instance not initialized

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, companion-object

I am trying to save an Application instance and use in the constructor of databaseHelper, but when my activity tries to instantiate the databaseHelper I get the following exceptions:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main Process: com.weatherupp.weatherupp, PID: 29092
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.weatherupp.weatherupp.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
[...]
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit 
property instance has not been initialized
```

the code leading to the exception is the following:

```
MainActivity {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
val provider = ForecastProvider()
[...]
}
```

ForecastProvider has the following companion object:

```
companion object {
    val SOURCES = listOf(ForecastServer(), ForecastDb())
}
```

ForecastDb's constructor refers to an instance of ForecastDbHelper, whose constructor refers to App.instance, declared as follows:

```
class App : Application() {

  companion object {
    lateinit var instance: App
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this
  }

}
```

If I comment all the code referring to the database, the app works using ForecastServer as the source of data, but the moment I try to refer to the database and hence to the App istance, Kotlin throws the UninitializedPropertyAccessException.

I have been looking at the code for hours, can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is blessed, thank all of you in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the App's onCreate is actually run? Might have forgotten to add it to the manifest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I lost three hours on this and did not notice that my breakpoint on App.onCreate were not doing anything.

Can you write it as an answer, so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot exactly pinpoint why your approach isn't working but I can suggest a fix:

You need a `ForecastDb` in your `MainActivity`. Your `ForecastDb` needs a `ForecastDbHelper`. Your `ForecastDbHelper` needs the `Application` instance.

So in your `MainActivity` you do:

```
val helper = ForecastDbHelper(application as App)
val db = ForecastDb(helper)
```

and voila, you got your db ready.

This is called dependency injection and gives you more control over creation of the objects 'fetching' their dependencies themselves.

**EDIT**: Also check if you added your `App` class as the `Application` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`like this::

```
<application
    android:name=".base.App" 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Kotlin expert but it seems that companion objects are initialized earlier that invoke of parent class constructor. Probably when your `val SOURCES` try to init it throws exception as it  try to use unitialized App instance (before App `onCreate()`). [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) you can read that ***a companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved), matching the semantics of a Java static initializer***

Comment: Good idea, I just tested though and my Applications onCreate is run before other classes are loaded, and I think this behaviour is guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing this out, I had not paid attention to this, but I think you need the annotation @JvmStatic to let them behave as such.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Please check if this statement is present in the app manifest

```
<application
android:name=".YourApp"
/>
```

in your case it should be

```
 <application
    android:name=".App"
    />
```